# dynamic form border, css

Tags: css, html, forms

I have a form, that may have 3 or 5 labels with input types (depending on some config elsewhere).

I have a border around this form, with fixed height and width. When the number of input types is 3, the form should be little bit smaller, and when the input types is 5, should be a little bit bigger, to accommodate the extra fields.

I would also like the text to be on the lhs, and aligned.

```css
/* code to reset the browser - compliments to meyerweb */
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 10px;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

.loginform {
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 width: auto;
 height:auto;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 border: inset 1px solid #333;
    border-size: auto;
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin: 10px 300px;
 margin-top: 45px;
 
 font-family: Tahoma;
 font-size: 12px;
}
.loginform ul {
    margin: 0;
}
.loginform li { 
   display:block;
   float:left;
   clear: left;
   width:auto; 
   height:15px; 
   padding: 10px;
}
.loginform li label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%; /* giving the label a width, makes sure the input boxes align */
}
```

```html
<section class="loginform">
    <form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <ul>  
            <li>
                <input type="text" >One</input>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="text" >Two</input>
            </li>
                <li>
                <input type="text" >Three</input>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </form>
</section>
```

Comment: at the moment there are three input types. Dynamically, two more can be added by my code. I would like the border property of the form, to adjust its size, so that it will always be bigger than the contents.

Comment: If it does not make any sense, you probably are not the right person to respond to the question. Lists can be dynamic, and if if it is dynamic, it means it can grow. if you make your form and its border a fixed size, then you will run into trouble, like I did here. The code snippet is just a mockup so people reading here can get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

The border does **not** control the size of the element so perhaps your understanding of what the border does is incorrect or you are using the work "border" when perhaps you mean "container".

A border is a decoration which sits on the outside edges of the element..it does not define the size of the element.

That being the case, I think the property you are looking for is `display:inline-block`:

```
.loginform {
    padding:20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: lightblue;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.loginform {
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 12px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="loginform">
  <form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="text">One</input>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="text">Two</input>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="text">Three</input>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </form>
</section>

<section class="loginform">
  <form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="text">One</input>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="text">Two</input>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="text">Three</input>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="text">Four</input>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="text">Five</input>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: nice one. Thanks